# Flutter - Container onPressed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this container:

```
  new Container(
    width: 500.0,
    padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 40.0, 20.0, 40.0),
    color: Colors.green,
    child: new Column(
      children: [
        new Text("Ableitungen"),
      ]
    ),
  ),
```

When the user clicks on the `Container`, I want an `onPressed()` method to be fired (like it can be done with `IconButton` for example). How can I achieve this behaviour with `Container`?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

You can use a `GestureDetector` widget like this:

```
new GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          print("Container clicked");
        },
        child: new Container(
          width: 500.0,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 40.0, 20.0, 40.0),
          color: Colors.green,
          child: new Column(
              children: [
                new Text("Ableitungen"),
              ]
          ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: I want to add on tap functionality to container .... have tried both inkwell and gesture detector as well but both are not working !!!

Answer (score 155):

**Don't use `GestureDetector`, it doesn't show ripple effect.** Use `InkWell` instead.

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {}, // Handle your callback
  child: Ink(height: 100, width: 100, color: Colors.blue),
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: FYI: If you use Container inside the InkWell then ripple may not appear if you also have the `decoration`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463515/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-when-used-with-container-decoration.
As shown by @CopsOnRoad use Ink, it supports almost all features as Container.

Comment: I want to add on tap functionality to container .... have tried both inkwell and gesture detector as well but both are not working !!!

Comment: ripple is not shown for me using container + decration

Comment: @KristiJorgji Yes, that's why you should use `Ink` and not a `Container`. However, you can set a color with some opacity in your container to see the ripple effect but it's more of a workaround and may not always fit your needs. So, better to use `Ink` as shown above.

Answer (score 22):

The simplest solution is to wrap the `Container` in a `GestureRecognizer`, but consider using an `InkWell` or `FlatButton` if you are building a Material design app. These widgets will show a visual splash response when touched.

Answer (score 16):

The container itself doesn't have any click event, so to do that there are two ways

1. InkWell widget
2. GestureDetector

In Flutter, InkWell is a material widget that responds to touch action.

```
InkWell(
    child: Container(......),
    onTap: () { 
        print("Click event on Container"); 
    },
);
```

GestureDetector is a widget that detects the gestures.

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () { 
        print("Click event on Container"); 
    },
    child: Container(.......),
)
```

**Difference**

InkWell is a material widget and it can show you a Ripple Effect whenever a touch was received.

GestureDetector is more general-purpose, not only for touch but also for other gestures.

Answer (score 5):

### Heading

**GestureDetector** vs **InkWell**

You can use two widget

**1) GestureDetector**

```
    GestureDetector(

        onTap: (){
          print("Container clicked");
        },
        child: new Container(child: ...)          
    );
```

This widget, doesn't have any effect.

**2) InkWell**

```
    InkWell(

        child: Container(......),
        onTap: () { 
            print("Click event on Container"); 
        },
    );
```

This widget has animation effect.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add on to [The Dumbfounds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7190575/the-dumbfounds) answer(accepted ans above)

If you are using **GestureDetector** or **InkWell** to handle the click of a group of icon and text, then use *Icon* widget instead of *IconButton* to display the icon as the onPressed method of IconButton  will take over the onTap method of GestureDetector/InkWell and as a result the onTap then will only work if you click on the text.

Example -

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _toggleFavorite();
        },
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: _isFavorited ? Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.red[500]) : Icon(Icons.star_border),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 18.0,
              child: Container(
                child: Text('$_favoriteCount'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
InkWell(
    child: Container(
    width: 500.0,
    padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 40.0, 20.0, 40.0),
    color: Colors.green,
    child: new Column(
        children: [
            new Text("Ableitungen"),
            ]
        ),
    ),
    onTap: () { 
        print("Tapped on container"); 
    },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

User can make button of any widget using `Inkwell` and `GestureDetector`.

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () { 
        print("Tapped"); 
    },
    child: Container(/* ... */),
);
```

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () { 
        print("Tapped"); 
    },
    child: Container(/* ... */),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Actual Answer of the question**

`InkWell` is the best from user experience.

```
 Container(            
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () { //handle your callback   },
          child: Ink(
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text('Click on me'),
            ),                  
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InkWell(
    child: Container(/* ... */),
    onTap: () { 
        print("Add your on tap event in this block"); 
    },
);
```

Use `InkWell` because it will provide you a nice material ripple effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GestureDetector` to give ontap on `Container`. Wrap `Container` with `GestureDetector` Widget:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () { 
        print("Please tap here."); 
    },
    child: Container(
        width: 500.0,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 40.0, 20.0, 40.0),
        color: Colors.green,
        child: new Column(
          children: [
            new Text("Hello"),
          ]
        ),
    ),
),
```