# Inkwell not showing ripple when used with Container decoration

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to add a ripple on an item, it is working fine until I add a gradient on the item using `BoxDecoration`.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
      child: Material(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
        elevation: 6.0,
        shadowColor: Colors.grey[50],
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
                end: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
                colors: [
                  Colors.yellow[800],
                  Colors.yellow[700],
                ],
              ),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Text(
              widget.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InkWell not showing ripple effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424621/inkwell-not-showing-ripple-effect)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found the solution:

I need one `Material` for `Inkwell`, and one `Material` for elevation and rounded borders.
The inner `Material` has a type of `MaterialType.transparency` so that it doesn't draw anything over the box decoration of its parent and still preserve the ink effect. The shadow and borders are controlled by outer `Material`.

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
      child: Material(  // <----------------------------- Outer Material
        shadowColor: Colors.grey[50],
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
        elevation: 6.0,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
              end: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
              colors: [
                AppColors.pinkDark,
                AppColors.pink,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Material(  // <------------------------- Inner Material
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            elevation: 6.0,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            shadowColor: Colors.grey[50],
            child: InkWell(  //<------------------------- InkWell
              splashColor: Colors.white30,
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.work,
                      size: 40.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          widget.title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: This, works buddy, one of the best solutions so far, Thankyou :)

Comment: So much work for a square button, thanks

Comment: This solution is not viable, many unnecessary widgets leading to poor performance.

Answer (score 114):

Update in 2019:

You should use `Ink` widget inside `Material`, instead of `Container`.
It takes `decoration` parameter as well:

```
Material(
      child: Ink(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          // ...
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: child, // other widget
        ),
      ),
);
```

Comment: That one helped me that the ripple effect is not behind the outer element. Now the ripple is visible overall in the clicked element!

Comment: Thank you. It works, but, despite being a "border-radius", when it clicked it pretends it's not there. Is this normal ?

Comment: This is the best answer, it's shorter. In fact it worked for me without the external Material widget.

Comment: @FatihMertDoğancan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410618/add-border-radius-in-the-inkwell-widget-in-flutter InkWell widget has the customBorder property.

Comment: There is no alignment property in `Ink`, so it cannot be a replacement for `Container`

Comment: This answer is very good.

Answer (score 12):

Simple splash effect widget I created that works perfect.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashEffect extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function onTap;

  const SplashEffect({Key key, this.child, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      child: InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
        child: child,
        onTap: onTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Splash color is overlap by container BoxDecoration

Try this

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(4.0)),
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
        end: AlignmentDirectional.topEnd,
        tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
        colors: [
          Colors.yellow[800],
          Colors.yellow[700],
        ],
      ),
      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
        new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey[50],
            //blurRadius: 0.3,
            blurRadius: 6.0,
            offset: new Offset(0.0, 4.0)
        )
      ]
  ),
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
  child: Material(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    //shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
    //elevation: 6.0,
    //shadowColor: Colors.grey[50],
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: const Color(0x8034b0fc),
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        //decoration: ,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(
          'Click',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

Comment: No, the result is bad, there is a greyish colour appearing on top of the item. I have already tried this approach.

Comment: You don't have to use nested material widget. I updated my solution. I think this will work. Material elevation was causing this problem. 


FYI: If any one solution does not work it, you shouldn't  down vote directly . First you have to let them know what problem you are facing. Then decide. Peace.

Comment: Yes the solution you gave is working, but I wanted shadow and radius from the `Material` itself, that was the thing I couldn't understand. Shadow was possible with BoxDecoration I knew, but wanted with `Material`. Sorry for the down vote though!

Answer (score 3):

If anyone came here looking to do use an inkwell with a circle decoration (like I did), I used the accepted answer to come up with this.

```
Material(
  child: Ink(
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.grey[350],
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 4.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
        onTap: onTap,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add, size: 48, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ));
```