# Add border Radius in the Inkwell widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

I want to add a hover color property to a container using the inkwell widget but the container has its own border-radius and when I am using the hover property using inkwell it is taking its custom shape and making it look rectangle in shape after hovering on the inkwell.

Here's my code snippet:

```
InkWell(
            
            onTap: () {},
            hoverColor: Colors.red[200],
            child: Container(
              width: 70.w,
              height: 60.h,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'images/call.png',
                    height: 30.h,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Call',
                    style: white,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I hope I made you understand the problem well

Please help me solve the issue or provide an alternate to it.

Comment: InkWell( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20) )

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The `Inkwell` widget has a property `customBorder` of type `ShapeBorder`. You can use that to provide a `borderRadius` to your `Inkwell`.

E.g.:

```
customBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
),
```

Comment: Check out @Sh4msi's answer below - there's a direct borderRadius property on InkWell

Answer (score 50):

The **Inkwell** widget has a property **borderRadius** of type **BorderRadius**

```
InkWell(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
  // ...
);
```

OR

```
InkWell(
  customBorder: CircleBorder(),
  // ...
);
```

Comment: this answer is more short and precise

Answer (score 7):

**Simple and New Approach/Solution**

I somehow agree with **@Matthias's** answer but if you need more realistic answer rather than giving `RoundedRectangleBorder` to `customBorder` property, then simply use `CircleBorder()` like an example below:

`InkWell(customBorder: CircleBorder(), // ... );`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the clip behavior to not have hard coded values when you have a widget that already has a border radius, eg a `Card` for example:

```
    return Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      child: InkWell(
```

Answer (score 5):

```
InkWell(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
  child: // ...
);
```

Answer (score 3):

To make splash also rounded, use suitable options of `clipBehavior` for `Material` widget.