# How do I clip clickable area of my container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Whole container is getting clicked, **other than circle** `shouldn't be clicked`.

I'm shaping my container to circle.

**What I want to do**

[image: img: What I want to do?]

Here's my code

```
 InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  hoverColor: Colors.yellow,
  child: Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`customBorder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse/customBorder.html) by providing [`CircleBorder()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/CircleBorder-class.html).

```dart
InkWell(
  customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
```

But for this case, you need to wrap with `Material` widget with `CircleBorder()`.

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=6a0d7d67f9a527d33a5602c3e735e35d)

The complete widget will be like

```dart
 Material(
  shape: const CircleBorder(),
  color: Colors.red, // container color,to have splash color effect
  child: InkWell(
    customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
    splashColor: Colors.white,
    onTap: () {
      debugPrint("tapped");
    },
    hoverColor: Colors.yellow,
    child: Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.transparent, // material color will cover this
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Reference [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51464163/10157127)

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But by wraping my inkwell with Material of shape CircleBorder is enough to work done, Why Ink & custom border is required ??

Comment: Thanks, I was following old fashion.  Also fixed an issue with splash color.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the child of your container with a stack and then give 2 children: one square container and one circular container both with the same colour and then wrap the circular container with a gesture detector or inkwell.
If tough to understand by only text let me know i will write the code snippet for you.
Do upvote if helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can populate the `borderRadius` property of the InkWell like this:

```
InkWell(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular('Your customized double value'),
  onTap: () {},
  hoverColor: Colors.yellow,
  child: Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem;

```dart
InkWell(
  customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
```

But if you want also material ripple effect on your red container you can use this code;

```dart
 ClipOval(
   child: Container(
     width: 300,
     height: 300,
     color: Colors.red,
     child: TextButton(
       onPressed: () {},
       child: Center(),
     ),
   ),
 ),
```