# How to add onclick function to image in a markdown in flutter?

Tags: flutter, markdown

I need to download the image file showing in the `MarkdownBody` in `flutter`. Is there any way to add function when image is clicked in markdown?

I have surfed for this but I got nothing.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions posted here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692923/flutter-container-onpressed

Comment: yes but it won't work

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you need `onPressed` method or `OnTap` on your image in markdown so wrap the entire image/markdown whichever widget you want in either `GestureDetactor` it has onPressed property or `InkWell` which has onTap Property and you can write your function inside

For Example refer this sample code

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          // Write you function/code
        },
        child: new Container(
          width: 500.0,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 40.0, 20.0, 40.0),
          color: Colors.green,
          child: AssetImage(asset/Image/sample.jpg),
        )
    );
```